# Gradle String Replacement - no placeholders

Tags: groovy, gradle

Is it possible to do simple string replacement in gradle where placeholders / tokens
can not be used.

For example: given `temp.txt` replace all occurences of `xxx` with `yyy`.

Comment: What do you mean _'...where placeholders / tokens can not be used'_?

Comment: The examples I've seen seem to require ${xxx} or @xxx@ as opposed to just xxx - maybe I'm misunderstanding the functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about resource processing. In that case, you can use the free-form `filter` method:

```
processResources {
  filter { String line -> line.replace(...) }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your example.

Comment: Downvoted because no context is given. Also it is not clear how a only single file could be processed.

Comment: It's the question that's missing context. The answer assumes that the context is resource processing (see first sentence).

Comment: where the snippet should be added?

Comment: I think this contains detailed explanation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:filtering_files

Answer (score 58):

Read the text in:

```
String contents = new File( 'whatever.txt' ).getText( 'UTF-8' )
```

Replace the text

```
contents = contents.replaceAll( 'xxx', 'yyy' )
```

Write the text out again

```
new File( 'replaced.txt' ).write( contents, 'UTF-8' )
```

You should be able to wrap them into a task and call the task as normal

Comment: good!! how to wrap it in a task: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html

Comment: How would you do this with a regex, like if you don't know to replace exactly **xxx** or **xx1** or **1xx1**?

Comment: Worked for me.  Just to be explicit to other newbs - this code goes right in your `build.gradle` script.

Answer (score 0):

To replace in-place:

```
ant.replaceregexp(file: fout, flags: "g",
      match: 'schemaLocation="[^"]+/', replace: 'schemaLocation="', encoding: 'UTF-8')
```

Reference for syntax:

- https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html
- https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) equivalent of @tim_yates [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10532883/8583692):

```kotlin
val file = file("whatever.txt")
val newContents = file.readText().replace(Regex("xxx"), "yyy")
file.writeText(newContents) // Overwrites the file with the new content
```