# Java project can't resolve gradle.build symbols

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm currently trying to build a project with gradle on windows, using a cygwin *nix emulator.
It's dependencies are being managed by maven, so gradle is only used to build the project and to deploy the code to a wildfly server.

With this being said I'm having some trouble getting build.gradle to resolve some default tasks. It builds and deploys anyways, but I'm getting a ton of warnnings and errors when I run wildfly.

Properties in the local_gradle.properties aren't being read.

[The kind of properties that are not being read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxph0.png)

Case in point - @jbossHome@ and @spCoreConfigDir@

[@jbossHome@ and @spCoreConfigDir@](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX8wy.png)

And finally, this is what makes me think that gradle is not properly installed?
Why does it build and deploy to the server without even resolving some basic symbols?

[Cannot resolve symbol task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efEH1.png)

This is what happens when I don't hardcode the paths:

Can anyone give me some insight on how to deal with this?
Cheers

PS: need 10 rep to post images, so bear with me.

Comment: Forgot the last pic but its a cygwin line throwing:

$ ./run-sp-wildfly.sh
./run-sp-wildfly.sh: line 19: @jbossHome@/bin/standalone.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: which version of gradle are you using?

Comment: also, can you post snippet of how you are populating the template? Normally, with Gradle if you have a `gradle.properties` in the project root, it should pick it up. Then you can create a task to replace your placeholders with the properties: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10532883/1695393

Comment: Sure. The team that developed this, basically used a "default properties file strategy". Properties are defined in the file, and they get it through properties.get(x); Like so:
https://imgur.com/a/3NYoev0

Comment: Right now im trying to hardcode some paths and validate the projects behaviour. PS: It's the latest Gradle version