# How to build your own custom filter closure in gradle copy task

Tags: gradle

I believe my context might be similar to this [Gradle String Replacement - no placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532632/gradle-string-replacement-no-placeholders)

I'm reading the gradle Copy documentation and indeed I want to do something like this:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html

```
from('XYZ') {
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [version: '2.3.1'])
}
```

The point is that however I cannot use the Replace tokens so I'm trying to use my own closure that will handle this.
I thought it would be quite easy but I just can't make it work because it's causing a weird error.

This is what I get:

```
copy {
    from "${project.buildDir}/tmp/tmp/${protobufName}/${protobufName}" {
        filter {
            String line -> line.replaceAll(A_PROTO_PACKAGE, B_PROTO_PACKAGE)
        }
    }
    into "${project.buildDir}/tmp/processed-protos/${protobufName}"
}
```

And gradle does not even work anymore after this because it really breaks the setup

```
Could not find method C:\dev\repo\connector-protos\build/tmp/tmp/authr_doc/authr_doc() for arguments [build_englvplwg0k6u9knec1bhhrel$_run_closure7$_closure21$_closure22@1a738cf4] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecWrapper_Decorated.
```

So in short the authr_doc is the first line of my file content but I really don't get why this does not work.
Any ideas? This might be really basic and my knowledge on closures is not that high but a simply string replacement should be really easy to do but somehow I'm stuck here

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution was here:
https://blog.mrhaki.com/2010/10/gradle-goodness-copy-files-with.html

It was probably just the way I was applying the filter that was in the wrong place:

```
copy {
    from "${project.buildDir}/tmp/${protobufName}/${protobufName}"
    into "${project.buildDir}/tmp/processed-protos/${protobufName}"
    filter {
        String line -> line.replaceAll(A_PROTO_PACKAGE, B_PROTO_PACKAGE)
    }
}
```